# Problem for read a .sql file and execute him and export for .csv file

Tags: python

I'm have a problem with python script.

I am starting to learn python and I have a challenge to change all my shell scripts to Python Scripts.

So I made the following script:

```
import csv
import MySQLdb
import sys
reload(sys)

conn = MySQLdb.Connection(host='MyHost', 
user='user',
                      passwd='pass', db='dbname')

fd = open('slect.sql', 'r')
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()

sqlCommands = sqlFile.split

print("database connected")

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sqlCommands)
result = cursor.fetchall()

with open('/tmp/newimport.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
     csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
     for row in result:
        csvwriter.writerow(row)

print("csv OK")

conn.close()
```

I'm unable to get Python to read a .sql file, execute it and after executing save the output to a .csv file.

Edit:

I'm receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newimport.py", line 18, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sqlCommands)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 198, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, TypeError, m)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
TypeError: query() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not builtin_function_or_method
```

Comment: what isn't working?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: I edit my post.

Comment: In your current example, the error is due to passing a method ref to `cursor.execute` since you have the line `sqlCommands = sqlFile.split`. If you intended `sqlCommands = sqlFile.split()` (add a delimiter as it's a whitespace by default which doesn't make sense with sql), `sqlCommands` will be a list that will still likely error `cursor.execute`. It might help if you provide an example of your sql file, you probably don't need to split it if it's just a single select query.

Comment: I forgot the delimiter in sqlFile.split, but fixed sqlFile.split (";"), but i'm getting a same error.